# What is the best schema solution to store billions of large arrays

Tags: mongodb

I have a large array in my crawling application something like this:

```
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5538ebbe265a286c54531d8c"),
   "word_frequency" : [
        [
            "words",
            NumberLong(5)
        ],
        [
            "sign",
            NumberLong(5)
        ],
        [
            "facebook",
            NumberLong(4)
        ],
        [
            "enter",
            NumberLong(3)
        ],

        etc more then 100 sub arrays in one _id 
}
```

The array is multidimensional and includes other multiple entries.
What is the best schema design to store this kind of values, for query and volume size perspective)? 
All in one as my example show it above or split array and create for each  array a separate item such

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5538ebbe265a286c54531d8c"),
"word_frequency" : [
        [
            "words",
            NumberLong(5)
        ]
}


{
"_id" : ObjectId("5538ebbe265a286c54531d8c"),
"word_frequency" : [
        [
            "sign",
            NumberLong(5)
        ],
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What queries shall the data structure support?

Comment: i.e find out which id has a most similarity if query source value xxxx

Comment: Perhaps you should consider something like [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org) for something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my personal opinion if you split and array and insert as separate item for each array it takes too much documents in collections, and second problem if you want to find out all `word_frequency` which contains `sign` then your query should be :

`find({"word_frequency":{"$elemMatch":{"$elemMatch":{"$in":["sign"]}}}})`

and it gives result back `array of array` means nested array like this

`"word_frequency" : [ [ "sign", NumberLong(5) ] ]`

In this case if you want to used this return results further then you should use some extra code logic to separate out nested array and here increase some looping over array and it takes times in processing.

As per my suggestion you should restructure your documents as below :

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5538ebbe265a286c54531d8c"),
  "word_frequency": [{
    "type": "words",
    "count": NumberLong(5)
  }, {
    "type": "sign",
    "count": NumberLong(5)
  }, {
    "type": "facebook",
    "count": NumberLong(4)
  }, {
    "type": "enter",
    "count": NumberLong(3)
  }]
}
```

In this case you should easily manged your documents and using following mongo functionality you can find how to query .

1> If you want to group by `type`, want to calculate `sum,avg,min,max` then [mongo aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) will help you.

2> If you want to add any other `type` in `word_frequency` then [mongo $push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) will help you.

3> If you want to update `type` then [mongo $pull](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) will help you.

Using this way you can create your document structure.

Comment: thx yohesh, this would be also easy to create an index see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/